determine if $ℚ(√i)$ a field but not ordered, or not even a ring
(just started learning about rings, fields)
Question :
I have determine if this is a field but not ordered, or not even a ring
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i}) = \left\{ a + b \sqrt{i} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, i^2 = -1\right\}$
My thought Process :
Starting with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$ :
checking for closure under multiplication
\begin{equation*}
    a + b \sqrt{i} \quad \text{and} \quad c + d \sqrt{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    a + b \sqrt{i} \times c + d \sqrt{i} \implies ac \space+\space(ad+bc)\sqrt{i} 
\space+bdi
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \quad \quad \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\implies (ac+bdi) \space+\space(ad+bc)\sqrt{i} 
\end{equation*}
$\space (ac+bdi)  \space\text{is  a complex number while }(ad+bc) \space \text{is an integer} \space $
. So can I immediately conclude this is not a field?
Another Thinking :
\begin{equation*}
     ac \space+\space(ad+bc)\sqrt{i} 
\space+bdi = \space ac + \space(ad+bc)\sqrt{i} + bd(\sqrt{i})^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space= (\space ac +0\sqrt{i}) \space+ \space(ad+bc)\sqrt{i} + (0+bd(\sqrt{i}))(0+\sqrt{i})
\end{equation*}
$\text{The first term, second term  and third term look like a standard element in that set.}$
$\text{Is that hinting that LHS is a standard element suggesting the set is closed under multiplication }$
Now division :
\begin{equation*}
    \text{Checking if an arbitrary element has an inverse in that set:} \quad
    (a + b\sqrt{i}) \times \left(a + b\sqrt{i}\right)^{-1} = 1 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
     \quad
     \left(a + b\sqrt{i}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{a + b\sqrt{i}} =\frac{a - b\sqrt{i}}{ a^2-b^2i} = \frac{a - b\sqrt{i}}{ (a^2+0\sqrt{i})-(0+ b\sqrt{i})^2}
\end{equation*}
here : $ a^2, \space 0 + b\sqrt{i} , \space a - b\sqrt{i} $ are all elements $\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$
$\text{I think for "'not ordered field "  part I could use direct contradiction}$.

How should I really understand how it is closed under multiplication
and division?.

Thank you for any input

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$ is a field by definition, and is stricly larger than $\Bbb Q+\Bbb Q \sqrt i$. It is equal to $\Bbb Q+\Bbb Q \sqrt i+\Bbb Q i+\Bbb Q i\sqrt i$.

The field generated by $\zeta_8 = \frac{1+i}2$ is not $\left{ a + b \zeta_8 ,\middle|, a, b \in \mathbb Q \right}$: it is a four-dimensional vector field over $\mathbb Q$ so you need to throw in $\zeta_8^2$ and $\zeta_8^3$ as well.

@PseudoNeo you mean $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$

@AnneBauval I am going by "For a set F to be a field, it must satisfy closure under addition and multiplication:".  addition is very direct, but for multiplication how should I see it. Am I to think that i is an element in that set thus can be expressed an (a+b sqrt(i)).

Malhari, were you given this task or did you invent it? If you were given it, are you sure you were not rather asked about $\Bbb Q(i)$?

Anne, it is a task

As said in my first comment, $i$ is an element of the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$ but not of the proper subset $\Bbb Q+\Bbb Q \sqrt i$.

Can you please double check the text of your task, then? Did you really report it word for word (and formula for formula)?

Doesn't the original exercise deal with $\mathbb Q(i) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ instead?

@AnneBauval Yes I checked, it is same Q. So far I understood that we are able to express for $i=\sqrt(i)*\sqrt(i) = (sqrt(i))^2$ . so, $i$ is an element of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$ and that makes field close under multiplication. Now, I can assume field is ordered and setting $sqrt(i)^2>0$  , squaring both sides. $i^2>0, -1>0$ a contradiction so field is not ordered. Is this understanding right?

$ad+bc$ is an integer?

The definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$ is not $ \left{ a + b \sqrt{i} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, i^2 = -1\right}$

Indeed, as repeatedly insisted on since the first comment above. So, if "it is same Q" then that "Q" is wrong. Who is it from? That said, your reasoning is correct proving that a field containing a square root of $-1$ is not orderable.

You "proved" that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$ is closed under multiplication using that $i = \sqrt i \times \sqrt i \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$. But saying that $i = \sqrt i \times \sqrt i \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$ uses that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt i)$ is closed under multiplication.
